# System format exception on outfrom from database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have the following bit of code:

```
    string updatestr= "UPDATE t1 SET  c3= @v3,c4=@v4,c5=@v5,c6=@v6 WHERE c2 = 'test' SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

    SqlCommand updatecmd= new SqlCommand(updatestr, conn);
    updatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v3",value3)
    updatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v4",value3)
    updatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v5",value3)
    updatecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v6",value3)
    object ind = updatecmd.ExecuteScalar();
    int distindex = int.Parse(ind.ToString());
```

Now I would expect the output of the scope identity to be an int (namely 29) however I get a format exception. at int.Parse(ind.ToString());. I printed the value of ind.tostring and for some reason it's test. Note that the first colum and the primairy key of the database (called id) is an autoincrementing int and I was hoping to select that. What am I doing wrong?

Oh and here is a better formated version of the query:

```
UPDATE t1
 SET  c3= @v3,c4=@v4,c5=@v5,c6=@v6
WHERE c2 = "test" 
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: Yhea I noticed that fixed that but that was only in the "simplified" example.

Comment: Aside from your current issue you should read this article. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: What happens when you execute your query directly in SQL Server?  What is the output?  Does this "simplified example" have a proven repro of the issue?

Comment: You are updating based on non primary key so there can be more that 1 updated row. Which one do you want in result? You are looking for `OUTPUT` clause I think...

Comment: It can output t he first one as both id and c2 and c3 are unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have said in comment:

> You are updating based on non primary key so there can be more that
>   1 updated row. Which one do you want in result? You are looking for
>   `OUTPUT` clause I think.

So the solution is to use `OUTPUT` clause with `Inserted` or `Deleted` virtual tables in case of `update` statement:

```
string updatestr= "UPDATE t1 SET c3= @v3,c4=@v4,c5=@v5,c6=@v6 
                   OUTPUT Inserted.id
                   WHERE c2 = 'test'";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Is for getting the auto-generated Id when a new row is INSERTED, in your case its an update so its probably returning null, you should use

```
select CAST(@@rowcount as int)
```

instead

Comment: Ah that's the problem. Still I don't think that rowcount is going to give me the correct id of the eddited row but instead the total number of rows?

Comment: Yes it will return the number of rows updated, but if you want the id of the rows edited i dont think theres a standard command that does that, you will have to do a select

Comment: So that would be simply appending select id to the query?

Comment: that would be one way, but like  @Giorgi Nakeuri mentioned in another comment since you are updating without using the primary key the result may be more than one row

Comment: I accepted @Girogi Nakeuri's answer but you noticed the orignal problem so I would like to thank you as well.

Comment: Yes i initially missed the part were you wanted the id of the row inserted and his answer is probably the best way to do it

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
int distindex = 0;
object ind = updatecmd.ExecuteScalar();
if(ind != null)
 int.TryParse(ind.ToString(), out distindex);
```